# Команда git push

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Когда я нахожусь в ветке `master`, то команда `git push` переносит мои локальный коммиты в общий репозиторий. А когда я нахожусь в другой ветке и пишу `git push`, то начинает происходить что-то странное. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что git push без параметров не обязательно будет отправлять текущую ветку. И не обязательно одну. А так как в основной ветке кто то сделал коммиты, то запушить свои изменения до pull'а не получится. Введите `git remote show origin` и увидите, какие ветки настроены на push и все прояснится.
Что бы избежать недоразумений, всегда явно указывайте ветку - `git push origin vetka`.